# Monitor Jobs state with Grafana in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, devops, prometheus, grafana, monitor

I have a lot of schedule pipelines in my Gitlab with a lot of jobs.
I need to have a tool to monitor the state of job (failure/success..)

Is possible to do that with Grafana.

I don't have an idea in details but I just started to learn it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are on self-hosted Gitlab, a lot of data are already exposed on an endpoint in Prometheus format.

If you are on SaaS, then you might want to check [Pipelines API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html) and [Jobs API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html).

You can use these to then make a custom exporter and scrape with Prometheus.
I made one using the [prometheus_client](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python) for python.